# Dependency Injection graph for Microservices

Tags: spring, rest, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have couple of REST bases micro-services which talk to each other through Eureka Server. I want to have a representation of which micro-service is exposed to what service or what endpoint is exposed to what...

I did found something like this but unable to use this in my scenario. Also the last update on this was in 2016. So not sure if this is reliable.

EDIT 1- Please have a look at following URL - "https://bintray.com/ordina-jworks/microservices-dashboard-server/microservices-dashboard-server#read"

[image]

Comment: Besides not being sure what you actually ask for, this looks more like a request-trace view, such as offered by AWS X-Ray, than a dependency-injection graph

Comment: @RomanVottner- AWS X-Ray provides ens to end request tracing mechanism. What I am looking for is some sort of depiction for where you can judge what microservice is dependent on which service without making a request. For ex- the snapshot I provided (though it is not working)  is telling me what endpoints are exposed to what service and not just one endpoint request (which is in the case of any tracing API like sleuth, zipkin, x-ray) at a time.

Comment: So basically something like [this](https://github.com/rlazoti/microservice-dependency-graph). Note that asking for the community to find or suggest libraries, frameworks or tools that may solve your needs is more or less considered off-topic as answers are likely to contain just opinionated views

Comment: @RomanVottner- thanks for the heads up for the off-topic discussion.. And yes something like this only I was looking for which I have also provided a link in my question above which uses spring boot. But that is not working so thought to take help here.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question and explain why the spring one is not working for you and ask for help to allow you to use the spring one, as this is for sure more on topic than asking for any tooling recommendations or the like.